# Confused on recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I don't understand the difference between these two functions, why does the one that returns the function work but the other doesn't?

The function returns the greatest common denominator between x and y assuming x > y

Non-working function:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    z = x % y
    if z == 0:
        return y
    else:
        gcd(y, z)
```

Working function:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    z = x % y
    if z == 0:
        return y
    else:
        return gcd(y, z)
```

Comment: How would you expect to get a value out of the first function if you don't return it?

Comment: Both functions work, it's just the first one doesn't return the result.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh After reading that, this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: In the first case, you're missing a `return` before the recursive function call. `return` makes the function "give you back" a value. Suppose you asked me to add up a list of numbers. I could simply add them up and keep the sum to myself... or I could tell you the answer. Telling you the answer (giving it back to you) is returning. Keeping it to myself (or throwing it away) is not returning, which is what you're doing in the first function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every function in python returns something.  In fact, you can put a `return None` statement at the end of every function in python without changing anything about how those functions work.  So your first function can be written

```
def gcd(x, y):
    z = x % y
    if z == 0:
        return y
    else:
        gcd(y, z)
    return None
```

So when I call `gcd(28, 14)` I get `None`.  When you `return` the recursive call to `gcd`, the code is equivalent to

```
def gcd(x, y):
    z = x % y
    if z == 0:
        return y
    else:
        return gcd(y, z)
    return None
```

so we either return `0` or whatever `gcd(y, z)` is, but never `None`, because the code never gets that far.